# Key-value consistency in python dictionaries

Tags: python

This is probably a noob question. For any dictionary 'd' in python is this always True:

```
dict( zip( d.keys(), d.values() ) ) == d
```

Are the keys and values returned in the same corresponding order ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's always true. Guaranteed by Python iff there are no intervening modifications to the ditionary.

Relevant spec: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

This is better generally, both because it protects against the dict going out of sync and uses negligible extra memory:

`dict((k,v) for k,v in d.iteritems())`

Comment: The unpacking is unnecessary though, `dict(d.iteritems())` works just as well. For that matter, most dicts (including `dict`) special-case mappings (over iterables in general) and do just that anyway, although I'm not sure if it's universal.

Comment: @delnan upvoted your comment, but I think keeping close to the example makes sense here.

Comment: You would never actually want to do `dict((k,v) for k,v in d.iteritems())` or `dict(d.iteritems())` because `d.copy()` is much better.

Comment: @delan dict(x) looks for x.keys and calls it to get an iterable of keys. If that works, it uses x[] to get all values and builds a dict from that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a guaranteed behavior :-)

The keys and values are listed in the same order as returned by *d.items*:  http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Note, in multi-threaded environments it is best to extract `d.items()` all at once rather than risk a mutation between successive calls to `d.keys()` and `d.values()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking whether the keys and values are returned in the same order, the answer is Yes. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) says:

> If `items()`, `keys()`, `values()`, `iteritems()`, `iterkeys()`, and `itervalues()` are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond.

If you're asking whether `dict( zip( d.keys(), d.values() ) ) == d` will always evaluate to True under all circumstances, the answer is No. You can have multiple threads, with one changing `d` while the other one is executing `d.keys()`, `d.values()`, or `dict(...)`. This will create intervening modifications, invalidating the conditions quoted above.